# Using final variable in JShell

Tags: java, jshell

I was trying to learn with JShell in JDK11,

jshell> final Integer val = 1

But I get a warning as :

|  Warning:
|  Modifier 'final'  not permitted in top-level declarations, ignored

Can I not use final in JShell or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You aren't in a class or a method; what does `final` mean outside that scope?